# Exporting Ui.chart in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, chart

I have a project where the user press on a district and then the app shows the temperature a s time series chart. I want to optimize all that calculation and save each chart instead of making the whole computation each time.

For that I need to export `ui.chart` like this :

```
var tempchart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(CollectioninCelsius, 
                       district, 
                       ee.Reducer.mean(), 
                       'Celcius', 
                        1000, 
                       'system:time_start', 
                       'PROJECT').setOptions(title);
```